# Who is funding the Beam mimblewimble development team?

Tags: funds, mimblewimble, beam

Since there is no-premine with the Beam mimblewimble project. How and who are funding their development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEAM had a private pre-sale, selling tokens to investors. They do not publish any of this information, but in their telegram and elsewhere there were estimates of 25 cents per token for a total of ~5 million dollars.

They say on their site they did not do an ICO, when in fact they did do a private ICO, which are by definition less tranparent and fair than public ICOs. It is up to the reader to interpret the motive behind their semantics.

Answer (score 1):

There are many investors of this project.

[INVESTORS](https://www.beam.mw/investors)

Lemniscap Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

Node Capital is investor at BEAM Mimblewimble

yeomans capital Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

PROTOS asset management Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

youbi capital Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

Alternity  is investor at BEAM Mimblewimble

1KX Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

Continue Capital Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

Mek Group  is investor at BEAM Mimblewimble

Ceyuan Ventures Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

hexa labs Investor of Beam Mimblewimble

Collider Ventures

EZRA